# How can I pull remotely stored PDFs to be viewed in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a site where PDFs are uploaded and stored (all exactly the same way) as (publicly available) attachments on a web page.

Using an Ionic app, I want to query the site and pull in the PDFs as a list where each item can be opened and read in the app. The PDFs would remain on the site/server, but would be available through the Ionic interface to be read as pages.

What kind of setup or services would I need for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you'd want an API that simply lists the available PDFs and the URL/Location for them.  That would be better than the ionic app trying to parse HTML from your existing site (which is what it sounds like you're considering).  Then the ionic app can call this service and get the PDF listing in JSON, which is very natural.

Then if the PDFs are externally accessible (meaning no token/security required),  the display of the PDF should be a simple `window.open()` call.

Comment: Thank you for helping me think this through!